# pandas - Select rows if row[i] is in row[j] for Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following Dataframe

```
id B C D
1  1 1 [1,2,3]
2  2 1 [1,2,3]
3  0 1 [1,2,3]
4  1 1 [0,1]
5  2 1 [0,1]
```

Column `D` of each row is a list. How could I select rows to form a new Dataframe so that every row satisfies: `B in D = True`?

For example, the result of above df will become:

```
id B C D
1  1 1 [1,2,3]
2  2 1 [1,2,3]
4  1 1 [0,1]
```

I tried with `df[df['B'] in df['D']]`, and it gives me the error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.

Comment: You should really post the full and correct requirements for your questions to avoid confusion and wasting people's time

Comment: @EdChum Yes I should have. Thank you for the answer still and sorry for the confusion. Will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to check whether each row satisfy the condition, and use the resulting boolean Series to do the slicing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[1,2,0,1,2], 'C' : [1,1,1,1,1], 'D':[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [0,1],[0,1]]})
print df[df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] in x['D'], axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   B  C          D  id
0  1  1  [1, 2, 3]   1
1  2  1  [1, 2, 3]   2
3  1  1     [0, 1]   4
```

This is based on the assumption that the column `D` is not the same across rows; otherwise, solution based on `isin` should be preferred as it is more efficient.